# How to display list items with jquery?

Tags: jquery

List items are not displaying. I put alert(htmlstr) to check whether htmlstr is properly taken or not. it looks fine. but list is not displayed i.e. bullets

```
var htmlstr = "<p><b>provided:</b></p><ul>";
  if(condition1)
  {
          htmlstr = htmlstr + "<li>DOB</li>";
  }
  if(condition2)
  {
          htmlstr = htmlstr + "<li>SSN</li>";
  }

htmlstr = htmlstr + "</ul>";
alert(htmlstr);
jQuery("#hello").empty().html(htmlstr);
```

but it is not displaying like this

provided:

- DOB
- SSN

Comment: If both conditions are true then that is a valid result.

Comment: what you mean by arrowmarks?

Comment: __"but it is not displaying like this"__ How is it displayed then?

Comment: and what does the alert(htmlstr) show?

Comment: @Andy  it is displayed without bullets

Comment: What is your CSS? The rest of your code?

Comment: you probably have somewhere in your stylesheets some styling of #hello ul li with arrowmarks.

Comment: @MrJack i think it is not related to css

Comment: Well you're the one that needs help, not I, so obviously you don't know much.

Comment: You do not need .empty(), .html(content) does that already

Comment: run it on firebug, look at the styling of the li

Comment: @PA. #hello is div element..jQuery("#xxx") is standard to call div element xxx

Comment: This is working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/YVC7j/ So maybe both your conditions are false?

Comment: As written above (with condition1 & 2 set to true) this works as expected: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/sBNCS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine. You dont need to change any stylesheet. If you have any content in `div` tag with id `hello` use `.empty()` otherwise just remove it.

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uGZ6L/)**</kbd>

Comment: The Fiddle Button . . How did you do that . . :|

Comment: use <kbd></kbd> tags to create button.